# React-Admin CSS theme overrides are placed earlier in <head> and getting overwritten by MaterialUI

Tags: material-ui, react-admin

After upgrading to React-Admin 3.15 (and `@material-ui/core 4.11.4` (styles as well)) we're running into some issues with styles. For example - for our sidebar `<MenuItemLink />` elements we've overridden the colors in the global theme, as recommended by [docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Buttons.html#menuitemlink). They *technically* work, they are inserted into the HTML head, but are placed *before* basic MaterialUI styles (like `.MuiButtonBase-root`) and those overwrite them.

[React-Admin's styles are inserted in the middle of head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYiYH.png)

This wasn't the issue prior to the upgrade (we used `react-admin@3.10.3` and `@material-ui/core@4.11.1`).

[Previously, RA styles were inserted at the end of head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sC8O.png)

I'm not really sure what code is relevant and we're kind of suspecting Next.js as well, so here's `pages/_app.tsx` and `pages/_document.tsx` (these files have not been changed during the update):

`pages/_app.tsx`

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  // remove server-side generated CSS once it's rendered, so it doesn't collide with styles generated on the client
  useEffect(() => {
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side')
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement?.removeChild(jssStyles)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <Provider session={pageProps.session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  )
}

App.getInitialProps = async (ctx: NextUrqlAppContext) => {
  const appProps = await NextApp.getInitialProps(ctx)
  return { ...appProps }
}
```

`pages/_document.tsx`

```
// is processed server-side only
export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <meta name="theme-color" content={theme.palette.primary.main} />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

// collects server-side generated styles, and saves them to head under #jss-server-side I assume
MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets()
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage

  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
    })

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    styles: [
      ...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles), 
      sheets.getStyleElement()
    ],
  }
}
```

The theme we're using is created in a file, exported and imported in the React-Admin's `<Admin />` component:

```
const theme = {
 //...
 overrides: {
   RaMenuItemLink: {
     root: {
       color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
       '&:hover': {
          backgroundColor: green[900],
          color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
       }
     },
     active: {
        backgroundColor: green[500],
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
     }
   }
  }
}
```

I also tried removing the `.next` folder, thinking maybe it's a cache issue, and hard-reload in browser too, to no avail.

*EDIT*: The styles seems even further inconsistent - e.g. two `<BooleanInputs>` with identical code (on different pages), yet one of them has `.MuiIconButton-root` overshadowing `.MuiSwitch-switchBase`, effectively turning off the `transition: left...` CSS property, while the other works fine. That happens because for some reason, `.MuiIconButton-root` is inserted into `<head>` *twice*, overwriting that property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you happen to stumble on the same problem as me - before trying anything else, do yourself a favor and try **deleting the entire `node_modules` and reinstall packages** if you can.

I thought I matched the `@material-ui` versions and was almost sure the problem is somewhere else and after 3 days of asking and trying to bandaid fix problems I randomly thought that maybe something really broke during the upgrade and well... doesn't hurt my chances to reinstall fresh. And it actually solved my issue.